# Probability of balls from urn

Tags: probability

Can someone please tell me if this is correct approach?

Suppose Urn 1 has 4 red balls and 3 white balls and Urn 2 has 3 red balls and 2 white balls. Two balls from each urn are drawn independently without replacement.

What is the probability that all four are red, and what is the probability that 3 are red and one is white?

I used independence and such and said

Let $ X=$ Number of red balls drawn from urn 1, and let $Y=$ number of red balls drawn from urn 2

then let $Z=$ number of red balls drawn total

$P(Z=4)=P(X=2 \cap Y=2)=P[X=2] \bullet P[Y=2]= (\frac{4}{7})(\frac{3}{6})+(\frac{3}{5}) \bullet(\frac{2}{4})=\frac{2}{7}+\frac{3}{10}=\frac{3}{35}$

However, I don't know if my method for saying the probability that X and Y were two is correct. I just did the probability that the first is red times the second.

For the second part I did $P[X=2 \cap Y=1 ] \bullet P[X=1 \cap Y=2]=\frac{12}{35}$ using the same method as above.

Does this look okay? On the right track? If so , could someone please confirm my numeric? if not please guide me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: You ended up with the right values, but I'm not sure how you got from $P(X = 2) \cdot P(Y = 2)$ to $(4/7)(3/6)+(3/5)(2/4)$, etc.  Did you mean to write $(4/7)(3/6) \times (3/5)(2/4)$?

Comment: Yes sorry this is what I meant and have written on my paper

Comment: OK, then I think you're fine.